# Where is the Tutorial Chest?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

A *lot* of mods add new items "to the tutorial chest", but none of them explain where that is.  There are several chests on the Nautiloid - which one is the "tutorial chest"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's one of the chests you encounter on the Nautiloid during the Prologue, labled as *Cartilaginous Chest*.

It's dubbed the 'Tutorial Chest' since this part of the game acts as the tutorial, and mods add stuff to this particular chest because it's at the start of a new game and easily identifiable.

The chest can be found on the second level, at coordinates [X:60 Y:-422](https://baldursgate3.wiki.fextralife.com/Cartiaginous+Chest), in the room mirroring that of the starting point, past the one in which we find Shadowheart's pod (see [here](https://mapgenie.io/baldurs-gate-3/maps/nautiloid?locationIds=291111) on the map).

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://www.nexusmods.com/baldursgate3/mods/457). Click for a more descriptive version, including the in-game map.

Note that the mod this screenshot is from allows for summoning the chest at any point in the game.</sup>